# Elastic Search issue with Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2.3.0, elasticsearch

I have installed Elasticsearch and it's showing below message when I run this command
 **curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'**

```
{
  "name" : "a_KnAuZ",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "S-RwARt0SZGKMjYHqIuu5g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "bd92e7f",
    "build_date" : "2017-12-17T20:23:25.338Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.1.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Also, it's showing https://prnt.sc/rz8hio connection success message but when I am running index management command then it's showing below error message for catalogsearch_fulltext

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_alias_name_exception","reason":"Invalid alias name [magento2_product_1], an index exists with thesame name as the alias","index_uuid":"MPr9O_RGTDKbDx4j4c8whg","index":"magento2_product_1"}],"type":"invalid_alias_name_exception","reason":"Invalid alias name [magento2_product_1], an index exists with the same name as the alias","index_uuid":"MPr9O_RGTDKbDx4j4c8whg","index":"magento2_product_1"},"status":400}
```

I am using Magento version 2.3.0 Version, how can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2.3.0 Only supports **ElasticSearch 5.x**.
You will need to updated to at-least 2.3.1. or use a lower version of ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed **ElasticSearch 6.1.1** `" number": "6.1.1",` based on the screenshot and You have configured ElasticSearch 5.0 + in Magento admin.

1. Change the **Search Engine** value to ElasticSearch 6.0 +
2. Change the **ElasticSearch Index Prefix** from **magento2** to **m2es6** or some other value.
3. clear cache and run catalog search indexer command again